# Browser totally blocked when I use guard children route in Angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, guard, canactivate

When I use **RoleGuard** in my '**pre-harvest**' children path and I open the browser the browser is totally blocked, it seems that is in an infinite loop. I don't have any compilation problem and I can't open the console to see what errors I have.

Is possible to use canActivate in children paths? or should I use CanActivateChild? I don't have this problem with CanActivateChild.

```
const preHarvestRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: PrivateComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
    children: [
      {
        path: 'pre-harvest',
        component: PreHarvestComponent,
        canActivate: [RoleGuard],  <------- IF I REMOVE THIS I DO NOT HAVE ANY PROBLEM.
        children: [
          {
            path: 'new-field',
            component: NewFieldComponent
          },
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

RoleGuard:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { CanActivate, Router, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot } from '@angular/router';
import { UserRolesService } from '../services/user-roles.service';
import { webStorage } from "../utils/web-storage";

@Injectable()
export class RoleGuard implements CanActivate    {

    constructor(
        private userRoles: UserRolesService
        , private router: Router
    ) { }

    canActivate( route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot )    {
        //let roles = route.data['roles'] as Array<string>;
        //let rolesUserLogged = webStorage.user;

        this.router.navigate( ['pre-harvest'] );

        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: To answer your last question. canActivate handle access on the current route and all its children. canActivateChild handle access only to the children of the current route, not to the route itself. Doc : https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#guards

Comment: You should add the code of your `RoleGuard` to see where the issue is

Comment: @PierreDuc I have added RoleGuard code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are redirecting to the same route as to where the `RoleGuard` is placed. This obviously results in an infinite loop. You should change your `RoleGuard` to this:

```
canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): boolean {
   //let roles = route.data['roles'] as Array<string>;
   //let rolesUserLogged = webStorage.user;
   return true;
}
```

You still have to specify your RoleGuard logic, but the issue you are having is redirecting to the same route.